# logWatch for monitoring catalina.out

Tags: tomcat

I am using logwatch and it is working good except for tomcat logs. There is no services in place for tomcat logs. Can any one help in configuring logwatch for monitoring catalina.out file?

Answer (score 1):

Add the file /etc/logwatch/conf/services/tomcat.conf,

Title = "Tomcat"

//Which logfile group...

LogFile = catalina

In file /etc/logwatch/conf/logfiles/catalina.conf,

LogFile = catalina.out

Place your filter as /etc/logwatch/scripts/services/tomcat. Logwatch will "cat" all the logfiles specified in catalina.conf and you program your filter to capture the interesting logs. Please refer http://www.stellarcore.net/logwatch/tabs/docs/HOWTO-Customize-LogWatch.html